# Bootstrap Datepicker - Set default picker date, NOT display value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap-Datepicker, and it's working really well.

One of the fields I'm using it for is a date of birth, and I know what the approximate age of the applicants is going to be, so it makes sense for me to default the picker to showing January 2000.

However, the only way I've found of doing this is to select a date, which actually updates the field with a value, which I don't want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datePickers = $('input[data-provide="datepicker"]');
    datePickers.each(function () {
        var datePicker = $(this);
        datePicker.datepicker('setDate', new Date(2000, 1, 1));
    });
});
```

[image: Date of Birth]

Is there a method in the object to select the view date or similar?

This is the default view I'm looking for:

[image: Default Month]

(Apologies if this is a duplicate - I looked but only found questions about how to actually pick dates.)

Comment: Look into using `defaultViewDate`: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate I can't wrap my head around the documentation, but that sounds like the right option (set the view date but don't actually change the value)

Comment: That looks really hopeful, but after much digging, trying to call it, searching the source code, I can't find any other trace of it. I did find some properties in the source called viewDate, but they don't seem to be exposed directly to the datepicker object.

Comment: Yeah, I hate this documentation... It's listed right there, but calling it `defaultViewDate: new Date(2000, 1, 1)` shows `January 2015` as the default view (which is closer, but not quite...) I'll keep trying, but being the end of the day on Friday, I might not be able to help for much longer...

Comment: As @tim suggests I'd try this: `datePicker.datepicker({defaultViewDate: {year:2000}});`

Comment: @tim, that's not how it is meant to be called. The first line of the doc says "Object with keys year, month, and day." You don't pass a date, you pass an object. I see your confusion at the top it says it can take a date... it lies.

Comment: @DanielCook Yeah, I just read that and posted my answer. I'm in php mode when it comes to dates and objects :P

Comment: Cheers guys, perfect :) Bootstrap-Datepicker documentation.. needs some work I think. Some basic usage examples would go a long way!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    defaultViewDate: {year:2000, month:0, day:1},
});
```

And the js Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mb34zwg3/

Comment: If you are getting date from model, you can use statement
$('#datePicker').datepicker(
            {
                defaultViewDate: '@Model.Date'
            });

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('input[data-provide="datepicker"]').data("date","2000-01-01");
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer by selecting the code part and pressing Ctrl + K to format it properly? I can not edit the answer because at least six characters are required to be edited and there is nothing more to do.